# Google Chrome extension: not all icons born equal?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Screenshot from chrome://extensions:
[image: chrome extensions sharp ico resolution]
Evernote is not my extension - this is just an example - my ico is blurry too.

Following [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/icons) I added a few icons into my extension, one of them is 128px - the maximum possible size. Maybe some preferences of exporting to the png?

Comment: You can add 256x256px too. Not sure it'll be used though as I don't have a HiDPI screen to test.

Comment: Thank you, I tried - but ico is the same.

Comment: You have some icon guidelines [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images). Notice the margin in the edges, maybe you need to make your icon a bit smaller and add transparent edges to avoid weird scaling.